# Connect MySQL database to an Android app

Tags: java, android, mysql

I need some help with connecting my mySQL database to my Android app I'm currently developing.

I've never done this before, and I found a couple tutorials [here](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/) it provides good information and I understand most of it, but it doesn't entirely work with my situation.

I have a database stored on a remote server my university provides and I access it using phpMyAdmin.

I need help connecting the app to the database so that way when users log in and registers for the app, it stores on the mySQL database. I was told I may need to use an SSH tunnel I have?

I've never done that before so I'm not too knowledgeable with that. Thanks guys!

UPDATE:I like the responses guys, thank you, I'm completely new to this so I'm learning as I go here. I do not know what the rest api is or how to implement it, it sounds like I need that. Also I do not just need log in verification, I need the app to add new users into the database as well in the registration screen.

Comment: http://androidbash.com/connecting-android-app-to-a-database-using-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

It would be done through Webservices. You need to develop web service and expose that webservice in android project.

That what is done in link you have given.

http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/

they have created webservice in php and call that webservice to authenticate username and password.

Comment: But I do not need to just authenticate username and passwords, I need the app to register new users as well into the database

Comment: for that also you can use RestAPI webservices.

Comment: I'm completely new to this, I have 0 ideas as to how to do that or what the rest API is or how to use it. There any examples or tutorials you know of that would help me with this?

Comment: For that you need to know server side coding in java, dot net and php. Let me give you reference link of RestAPI. http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/jaxrs-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

better develope a server-side module which caters your db needs , and access it using HTTP requests from android app.

you need.

1) One web-application (probably exposing REST api)

2) above web-application, connecting to mysql using jdbc

3) http client framework in your android app (client)

Comment: What do you mean a web application? Recreate the app as a web application? Or use a web application to connect the two?

Comment: use a web-application which acts as a Facade between db and your android client.